# FirebaseInstanceID ARC Semantic Issue Swift Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am getting this error on build after installing the Firebase/Messaging pod and configuring as shown on the official Firebase documentation. I am on the latest pods, I have done pod update, I have updated cocoapods. Any suggestions on how to fix?

```
No visible @interface for 'FIRInstanceIDAuthKeychain' declares the selector 'setData:forService:accessibility:account:handler:'
```

Comment: What are the versions of the `FirebaseMessaging` and `FirebaseInstanceID` pods listed in the Podfile.lock? Where is the error occurring?

Answer (score -1):

The issue has been fixed, after installing the Firebase/Messaging, and Analytics pods the actual pod files stored in Pods > Pods > FirebaseInstanceID & FirebaseFirestore were being duplicated. E.g. File.m, File.h & File 2.m & File 2.h. After deleting all of the duplicate files and removing all references, the build succeeded.